# Modes of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If `|f(x)-f_N(x)|` does not converge pointwise on a closed interval. Does this imply `|f(x)-f_N(x)|` does not converge uniformly on that internal?

I want to say yes, but I am not sure, and I do not know what definitions, theorems, etc. to reference.

Comment: Yes, since uniform convergence $\;\implies\;$ pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that:

> **Pointwise convergence is necessary for the uniform convergence of a function; however, a function which is pointwisely convergent may be not uniformlt convergent.**